# tf.sparse.reshape(tf.sparse.split()) : TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to convert a dense matrix to sparse matrix calcualtion on tensorflow. There is an error when trying to `reshape` after using `tf.sparse.split(`. Following is a toy example to demonstrate the issue.

**Tensorflow dense matrix**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
a = np.array([[1, 0, 2, 0,0,1], [3, 0, 0, 4,1,0]])

a_t = tf.constant(a)
a_t_rshp = tf.reshape(tf.split(a_t,2,axis = 1),[2,2,3])
```

**Tensorflow sparse matrix**

```
a_t_st = tf.sparse.from_dense(a_t)
a_t_st_rshp = tf.sparse.reshape(tf.sparse.split(a_t_st,2,axis = 1),[2,2,3])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-3dff37aef5b4> in <module>
----> 1 a_t_st_rshp = tf.sparse.reshape(tf.sparse.split(a_t_st,2,axis = 1),[2,2,3])

/Users/Mine/Python/tf2_4_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py in sparse_reshape(sp_input, shape, name)
    886     ValueError:  If `shape` has more than one inferred (== -1) dimension.
    887   """
--> 888   sp_input = _convert_to_sparse_tensor(sp_input)
    889   shape = math_ops.cast(shape, dtype=dtypes.int64)
    890 

/Users/Mine/Python/tf2_4_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py in _convert_to_sparse_tensor(sp_input)
     70     return sparse_tensor.SparseTensor.from_value(sp_input)
     71   if not isinstance(sp_input, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
---> 72     raise TypeError("Input must be a SparseTensor.")
     73   return sp_input
     74
```

can you please help me to overcome this issue?

Comment: i did not have any issues at all with your code. I'm running on python 3.7 and tf 2.4 what version are you using?

Comment: @CrazyBrazilian did you try running `a_t_st = tf.sparse.from_dense(a_t)
a_t_st_rshp = tf.sparse.reshape(tf.sparse.split(a_t_st,2,axis = 1),[2,2,3])` ? 

versions : Python 3.6.4 and TensorFlow  2.4.0

Comment: Seems like this is bug in Tensorflow, could you raise this issue in Tensorflow github reporository https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues. Thanks!